# how to adjust listbox width according to the models item text size in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I am just looking to adjust the listbox width according to the model's item text size in qml. Is it possible, any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paintedWidth` property of text in `Component.onCompleted` method of item and change `parent.width` accordingly.